# Help finding CG coefficient in Wigner-Eckart Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

Here is a Wigner-Eckart problem from class that I am having trouble understanding.

$$\langle 310|T_{10}|300\rangle =\langle 31||T_1||30\rangle\langle 10;00|10\rangle $$

where $\langle 10;00 | 10\rangle =1$.

I believe the form my professor has followed is $\langle kq;l_2m_2|l_1m_1\rangle $.

I'm having trouble seeing how the CG coefficient is equal to 1.  Could anyone explain?

Comment: What are the possible $j$ values you can obtain by adding $j_1 = 1$ to $j_2 = 0$?

Comment: @theindigamer:  Thanks for your response.  Do you mean $|j_1-j_2|\leq j \leq j_1+j_2$?  If so, I guess that means j can only equal 1...

Comment: Correct. What is the next step? Consider the $m$ values. You have $q+m_2=m_1$. So the CG coefficient is most likely non-zero. Further, can you have any other possible combination of $q$ and $m_2$ (while keeping $k$, $l_2$ fixed) so that $q+m_2=m_1$ is still satisfied?